# 0x: Is it possible to fill an order from a smartcontract?

Tags: 0x

When I try to fill an order with funds from a contract I get the following generic error:

> Error: Transaction:
>   0x1d3161cd7f318c3b0b28fc34b2c6bca0cbf4efdb3b11fcf7ec3af7c9adfd821b
>   exited with an error (status 0). Reason given: TRANSFER_FAILED.
>        Please check that the transaction:
>        - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
>        - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.

I've got the following contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

Exchange exchange;
EthForERC20Token crowdsale;
WrapERC20Token wrapERC20Token;

constructor(
    address _exchangeAddress
) 
public 
{
    // The local 0x exchange intstance
    exchange = Exchange(_exchangeAddress);
    // Grand unlimited allownace to the exchange contract.
    wrapERC20Token = new WrapERC20Token(address(exchange)); 
}

function fillOrder (
    Exchange.Order memory _order, 
    uint256 _assetFillAmount,
    bytes memory _signature
) 
public 
payable
{
    exchange.fillOrder(_order,_assetFillAmount, _signature);
}

function getWrappedERC20Address() 
public 
view 
returns(address) {
    return address(wrapERC20Token);
}
```

I tested and the contract owns enough of the WrappedERC20Token which is just an ERC20 token with the option to pre-approve an address with unlimited allowance.

My 0x order creation is as follows:

```
const wrappedShareAddress = await contract.getWrappedShareAddress();
const maker = accounts[0];
const makerAssetData = zeroX.assetDataUtils.encodeERC20AssetData(etherToken);
const takerAssetData = zeroX.assetDataUtils.encodeERC20AssetData(wrappedShareAddress);
const contractWrappers = new zeroX.ContractWrappers(providerEngine, { networkId: 50 });


const order = {
            exchangeAddress: exchange,
            makerAddress: maker.toLowerCase(),
            takerAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
            senderAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
            feeRecipientAddress: NULL_ADDRESS,
            expirationTimeSeconds: (1581437362).toString(),
            salt: zeroX.generatePseudoRandomSalt().toString(),
            makerAssetAmount: new zeroX.BigNumber("5e17").toFixed(),
            takerAssetAmount: new zeroX.BigNumber("5e17").toFixed(),
            makerAssetData,
            takerAssetData,
            makerFee: new zeroX.BigNumber("0").toFixed(),
        takerFee: new zeroX.BigNumber("0").toFixed(),
        };
        // console.log(order);
        // Generate the order hash and sign it
        const orderHashHex = zeroX.orderHashUtils.getOrderHashHex(order);
    signature = await zeroX.signatureUtils.ecSignHashAsync(providerEngine, orderHashHex, maker);
        signedOrder = {...order, signature};
    const makerWETHApprovalTxHash = await contractWrappers.erc20Token.setUnlimitedProxyAllowanceAsync(
            etherToken,
            maker,
        );

        await toTxhash.mineTx(makerWETHApprovalTxHash);

        const makerWETHDepositTxHash = await contractWrappers.etherToken.depositAsync(
            etherToken,
            new zeroX.BigNumber("2e18"),
            maker,
        );

        await toTxhash.mineTx(makerWETHDepositTxHash);
```

Then I call the smart contract function using:

```
    const res = await contract.fillOrder(
        signedOrder,
        new zeroX.BigNumber("5e17").toFixed(),
        signature,
        {from: maker, value: new zeroX.BigNumber("1e18").toFixed()}
    );
```

Comment: It is not wise to use `10 ** 18` in Javascript, since it is larger (much larger) than the [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Use `"2e18"` instead of `2 * 10 ** 18`, or `"5e17"` instead of `0.5 * 10 ** 18`, or `"1e18"` instead of `10 ** 18`, etc. If you need to utilize values that are "more complicated", then `require("bignumber.js")` and use `BigNumber` objects wherever needed. You can convert such object to a full-precision string via the `toFixed()` function.

Comment: You do realize that `.toString()` is redundant in the expression `("5e17").toString()`, yes?

Comment: Was still busy editing, thanks for the comments.

Comment: Also, why did you use `new` for the initialization of `wrapERC20Token ` but not for the initialization of `exchange`? Since you have no `require` or `revert` statements in your code, this is a good candidate for your transaction failure (later in your code, when you call `exchange.fillOrder`, for example).

Comment: P.S.: the string returned by `new zeroX.BigNumber("5e17").toFixed()` is `"500000000000000000"`. Although it is different from the string `"5e17"`, when converted back to a `BigNumber` instance, they will yield the same object. And when you call `fillOrder`, this string is eventually converted to such an object. So you may as well use the simplest notation possible, which is `"5e17"`. I meant for you to use `toFixed()` when handling a value **returned** from some contract function, since `toString()` may convert it to scientific notation, and then you might end up "losing some digits".

Comment: I don't use ```new``` for the exchange because there already is a 0x exchange contract live on my ganache provider. Should be no need to deploy a brand new one you'd think.

Comment: It does revert somewhere in the ```exchange.fillOrder``` function

Comment: So you should investigate this function or post its code here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89631/discussion-between-jasper-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your contract needs to approve the 0x ERC20Proxy to move your ERC20 tokens.

For example, take a look at the [Forwarder contract](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/blob/development/contracts/exchange-forwarder/contracts/src/MixinForwarderCore.sol#L53) which does this in the constructor.